# Packaging a java project with Apache derby database

Tags: java

I have a java Database project using Apache Derby. It works fine on Eclipse IDE. But after Packaging the project into a runnable JAR, the software
is unable to load and save database.

```
// JDBC CONNECTION METHOD
public void connect() throws Exception{

    if(con != null) return;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("Driver not found");
    }

    String url = "jdbc:derby:src/MyDB;create=true";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}

//JDBC DISCONNECITON METHOD

public void disconnect(){

    if(con != null){
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

// SAVING DATA INTO JDBC DATABASE
public void save() throws SQLException{

    String checkSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM appData.stock WHERE id =? ";
    PreparedStatement checkStmt = con.prepareStatement(checkSQL);

    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO appData.stock(productName,unitPrice,quantity,manufacturer,stockDate,value) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement insertStmt = con.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

    for(Product product : stock){
        int id = product.getId();
        String productName = product.getProductName();
        float price = product.getProductPrice();
        int quantity = product.getQuantity();
        String manufacturer = product.getManufacturer();
        String date = product.getDate();
        float value = product.getValue();

        checkStmt.setInt(1, id);

        ResultSet checkResult =  checkStmt.executeQuery();
        checkResult.next();

        int count =checkResult.getInt(1);

        if(count == 0){
            int col = 1;
            //insertStmt.setInt(col++, id);
            insertStmt.setString(col++, productName);
            insertStmt.setFloat(col++, price);
            insertStmt.setInt(col++, quantity);
            insertStmt.setString(col++, manufacturer);
            insertStmt.setString(col++, date);
            insertStmt.setFloat(col++, value);

            insertStmt.executeUpdate();

        }
    }

    UIManager.put("OptionPane.buttonFont", new FontUIResource(new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN,26)));
    JLabel message = new JLabel("Your Stock Database has been Updated and Saved");
    message.setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN,21));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

    checkStmt.close();
    insertStmt.close();
}

//RETRIEVING  DATA FROM DATABASE IN JDBC
public void load() throws SQLException{
    stock.clear();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM appData.stock ";

    Statement selectStatement = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet result = selectStatement.executeQuery(sql);

    while(result.next()){
        int id = result.getInt("id");

        String productName = result.getString("productName");
        float price = result.getFloat("unitPrice");
        int quantity = result.getInt("quantity");
        String manufacturer = result.getString("manufacturer");
        String date = result.getString("stockDate");
        float value = result.getFloat("value");

        Product product = new Product(id,productName,quantity,price,manufacturer,date,value);

        stock.add(product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Asaana You say it works fine in eclipse so that leads me to believe that now you're running outside of IDE, the derby.jar file is not in your classpath.

Try this if you haven't already done so...

When you create your jar file, (assuming you import manifest information) , put derby.jar in the Class-Path header of your manifest.txt file

Eg.
In your manifest.txt file:

Include this:

Class-Path [derby_home]\lib\derby.jar

Where [derby_home] is where your derby is located.
This off the top of my head as I'm not near my screen. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

@Ingrid After packaging it into a runnable Jar file,my software is able to find the derby.jar file but its unable to find my Database SCHEMA and saved data.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see. Correct me if I'm wrong but you created your tables inside the IDE. You need to create your tables from within your application directly (as shown below) or via a script.

What follows is an example of creating a database, adding tables and inserting data directly from within your application. 
The database (MyDB) will be created in your project folder (the folder where you launch your application.)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class DerbyExample {    

    private Connection con = null;    
    private final String dbName = "MyDB";    
    private final String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
    private PreparedStatement psInsert;      
    private Statement s;

    public DerbyExample () throws SQLException {
       try {                
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName + ";create=true");
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            con = null;
        }
        if (con == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not create/connect to shop database! - Contact System Administrator.     ");
            System.exit(1);
        }            
        con.setAutoCommit(false);            

            s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            s.execute("create table CATEGORIES(CATEGORYID int NOT NULL, CATEGORYNAME varchar(20))");
            s.execute("ALTER TABLE CATEGORIES ADD CONSTRAINT CATEGORYID_PK PRIMARY KEY (CATEGORYID)");
            psInsert = con.prepareStatement("insert into CATEGORIES values (?, ?)");
            psInsert.setInt(1, 1);
            psInsert.setString(2, "Breakfast");
            psInsert.executeUpdate();
            psInsert.setInt(1, 3);
            psInsert.setString(2, "Coffee");
            psInsert.executeUpdate();
            psInsert.setInt(1, 4);
            psInsert.setString(2, "Dessert");
            psInsert.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from CATEGORIES");
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }            
            rs.close();          

            disconnect();           
        }
     public void disconnect(){
        // Shutdown Derby
        try {
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {}

        // Close statement (PreparedStatement extend Statement)               
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
                s = null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {}           
        }
        // Close connection
        if(con != null){
            try {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException  {  

        DerbyExample ex = new DerbyExample();        
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solution solves your problem. You can find plenty of information  in the [Derby Reference Manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/refderby.pdf) and the [Derby Developer's Guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/derbydev.pdf) and examples [here](http://C:%5CApache%5Cdb-derby-10.12.1.1-bin%5Cdocs%5Chtml%5Cgetstart%5Cindex.html).

Comment: @Asaana You are welcome. Mark the answer as correct if it answered your question. Thanks ;)