# How to make an installation file from java project and derby database?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, installation

I read couple of topics but didn't find a good answer.
I used netBeans IDE and created a program (using GUI)
and using a derby database (threw the netBeans IDE)
and now when I'm finished I want to create one single file that I can send to my friends that contains the app and also the database.

1. if there an option like this (like creating a runnable jar file + database included).
2. if not, is there a free-web-hosting to upload my database in?
   if there is, please add a tutorial that explains how to do it.
   and how to use this databse in my program (what url to get the Connection)
   (the database is not big, only 3 tables with some lines in them).

*all of the url-paths I used are project-based (in the project folder - the databse url, files url and so...)

Thank you in advance, sorry for the English mistakes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522020/packaging-a-java-project-with-apache-derby-database

Comment: first of all - thank you!
if I understaned correctly this guy problem was that he used the IDE to create tables and insert data, and that's why it failed.
if I want to create database, that alrady have data in it that the program uses it, and when sending it to another computer the data would be saved? can I do that?

BTW if you can answer my second question also I would be glad.

Comment: You have to determine if u want an embedded database wich works for itself and with data for every user or a shared database for all of them. If you want one for user then you can use an embedded database, if u want the same database for all of them then you should get a hosting for it

Comment: I have one database with 3 tables: two tables holds user information that can and would be changed, the third one holds information that can't and not needed to be changed.
what can I do to pack this database (with the 3 tables) to my project?

EDIT: I'll be more specific:
1 table - holds user names and password.
2 table - holds shift information (work shifts).
3 table - hold some timezone data that can't be changed that I use to calaculate things in the 2 table.